# Command like `column -t` that instead keeps separators in output

Tags: text-processing, software-rec

I'm editing a simple table.  I would like to have it nicely formatted.  While I could use `tbl`, `latex`, or similar, this seems overkill -- plain text really is sufficient.  As it's simple I might as well have the source be the output.  So the source should look good too.   This seems like it should be a perfect job for `column -s '|' -t` -- it finds the separators and automatically inserts spaces to align according to the maximum width in each column.   Unfortunately, it deletes the separators, so I can't rerun it after further editing.  Is there any good text-processing tool that can do this idempotently, so that it's output serves as input?  Or do I need to write my own?

EDIT: here's an example of what I want:

```
foo |   bar | baz
abc def | 12 | 23456
```

should become

```
foo     | bar | baz
abc def | 12  | 3456
```

When `' '` is both the separator and the spacer, `column -t` works nicely.  But my items have spaces in them, so I can't use that.
Having the spacers be distinct from the separators complicates things.  I think it's useful to have them be treated as separator characters when next to separators, but that's not what `column -s '|' -t` does (though obviously the current behavior is also useful).

Comment: You could use emacs org-mode.  The table support is actually quite amazing, providing spreadsheet like functionality.

Comment: Not as general as what I thought would be reasonable, but there's a python program specifically for markdown tables at http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2008/08/tables-for-markdown-and-textmate/ .

Comment: This is a problem I run into like at least every two weeks. The only viable solution to bypass `printf` holocaust each time, that I have found so far, is adding a unique char (like `@`) into the data, and use `... | column -s@ -t` afterwards.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure if I understand right what is your problem. But, can it be solved adding an additional temporal separator? hence you can use the second separator to mark the separations, keeping the original separator untouched.

See this example where I add a "@" to each of the "|" so the input of the column command would be "xxx @| yyyy". Column will process the "@" keeping the "|" untouched:

```
~$ echo "foo | this is some text | bar" | sed 's/|/@|/g'  | column -s '@' -t
foo   | this is some text   | bar
```

Comment: Clever.  Nearly does what I want, and does in fact do what I asked -- leaves the separators in.  I also want the spaces next to the true separators to be able to be adjusted down, rather than just up, as here.

Comment: @wnoise: use `sed 's/ *| */@|  /g'` instead

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: And adding `sed 's/  |/|/g'` after the `column` fixes the extra spaces added.  We now have a solution that works well enough for me.  (Though it'd be nice if it didn't depend on an extra character like this.  What if one isn't available?)

Comment: @wnoise: Instead of @, you can use something that typically does't appear in text, like a low ASCII value, eg. $'\x01'... (but not $'\x00')...

Answer (score 20):

This wasn't available when you asked the question but [as of v. 2.23](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=47bd8ddc5b72739cf30f287ce84c984eb05b124e) `column` from `util-linux` allows you to select the output separator via

```
   -o, --output-separator string
          Specify the columns delimiter for table output (default is two spaces).
```

So simply run:

```
 column -s '|' -o '|' -t infile
```

Comment: Note that the `util-linux` version is not available on Ubuntu 18.04 (and probably other Debain derived distros) at the time of writing. Only the `bsdmainutils` version is available. The `bsdmainutils` version does not support output formatting.

Comment: (and in more layman English - the Mac OS version of `column` doesn't have the `-o` version :( )

Answer (score 6):

Here is a bash script. It does not use 'column -t`,
and the seperator is handled exactly as is the IFS,
because it is the IFS (or at least, awk's internal version of the IFS)... The default delimiter is $' \t'

This script fully pads out the rightmost field.
'column' does not do this.
By padding out all the columns, this script can be
easily modified to create a table frame as well.

Note. The input file needs to be processed twice
('column' would also need to do this)
The first pass is to get column max widths.
The second pass is to expand fields (per column)

*Added some options* and fixed a glaring bug (renaming variables :(

- -l  Left trim whitespace of any indented fields
- -r  Right trim whitespace wider than widest text (for the column)
- -b  Both -l and -r
- -L  Left output delimiter is added
- -R  Right output delimiter is added
- -B  Both -L and -R
- -S  Choose output seperator

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#   script [-F sep] [file]
#
#   If file is not specified, stdin is read 
#    
# ARGS ######################################################################
l=;r=;L=;R=;O=;F=' ' # defaults
for ((i=1;i<=${#@};i++)) ;do
  case "$1" in
    -- ) shift 1;((i--));break ;;
    -l ) l="-l";shift 1;((i-=1)) ;;        #  left strip whitespace
    -r ) r="-r";shift 1;((i-=1)) ;;        # right strip whitespace
    -b ) l="-l";r="-r";shift 1;((i-=1)) ;; # strip  both -l and -r whitespace
    -L ) L="-L";shift 1;((i-=1)) ;;        #  Left output delimiter is added
    -R ) R="-R";shift 1;((i-=1)) ;;        # Right output delimiter is added
    -B ) L="-L";R="-R";shift 1;((i-=1)) ;; # output Both -L and -R delimiters
    -F ) F="$2";shift 2;((i-=2)) ;; # source separator
    -O ) O="$2";shift 2;((i-=2)) ;; # output  separator. Default = 1st char of -F 
    -* ) echo "ERROR: invalid option: $1" 1>&2; exit 1 ;;
     * ) break ;;
  esac
done
#
if  [[ -z "$1" ]] ;then # no filename, so read stdin
  f="$(mktemp)"
  ifs="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'; set -f # Disable pathname expansion (globbing)
  while read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line" >>"$f"
  done
  IFS="$ifs"; set +f # re-enable pathname expansion (globbing)
else
  f="$1"
fi
[[ -f "$f" ]] || { echo "ERROR: Input file NOT found:" ;echo "$f" ;exit 2 ; }
[[ -z "$F" ]] && F=' '        # input Field Separator string
[[ -z "$O" ]] && O="$F"       # output Field Separator
                 O="${O:0:1}" #   use  single char only

# MAIN ######################################################################
max="$( # get max length of each field/column, and output them
  awk -vl="$l" -vr="$r" -vL="$L" -vR="$R" -vF="$F" -vO="$O" '
    BEGIN { if (F!="") FS=F }
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
        if (l=="-l") { sub("^[ \t]*","",$i) }
        if (r=="-r") { sub("[ \t]*$","",$i) }
        len=length($i); if (len>max[i]) { max[i]=len } 
        if (i>imax) { imax=i } 
      } 
    }
    END { for(i=1;i<=imax;i++) { printf("%s ",max[i]) } }
  ' "$f" 
)"

awk -vl="$l" -vr="$r" -vL="$L" -vR="$R" -vF="$F" -vO="$O" -v_max="$max" '
  BEGIN { if (F!="") FS=F; cols=split(_max,max," ") }
  { # Bring each field up to max len and output with delimiter
    printf("%s",L=="-L"?O:"")
    for(i=1;i<=cols;i++) { if (l=="-l") { sub("^[ \t]*","",$i) } 
                           if (r=="-r") { sub("[ \t]*$","",$i) }
      printf("%s%"(max[i]-length($i))"s%s",$i,"",i==cols?"":O) 
    } 
    printf("%s\n",R=="-R"?O:"")
  }
' "$f"

# END #######################################################################    
if  [[ -z "$1" ]] ;then # no filename, so stdin was used
  rm "$f"   # delete temp file
fi
exit
```

Comment: Nicely done.  Of course, I was hoping for something that wouldn't actually require writing a new program.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the vim plugin called Tabularize

```
:Tabularize /<delim>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-pass tweak on [*hmontoliu*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18717/165517), which avoids needing to hard code the delimiter, by guessing it from the input data.

1. parse input for single non-alphanumeric characters surrounded by spaces, sort them by which is most common, and assume the most common character is the delimiter, which is assigned to `$d`.
2. proceed more or less as in *hmonoliu*'s answer, but use an ASCII *NULL* as padding, instead of an `@`, as per *PeterO*'s comment.

The code is a function which accepts a filename, or else input from *STDIN*:

```
algn() { 
    d="$(grep -ow '[^[:alnum:]]' "${1:-/dev/stdin}"  | \
         sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed -n '1s/.*\(.$\)/\1/p')" ;
    sed "s/ *$d */\x01$d /g" "${1:-/dev/stdin}"  | column -s $'\001' -t ;
}
```

Output of `algn foo` (or also `algn < foo`):

```
foo      | bar  | baz
abc def  | 12   | 23456
```

Comment: Looking at this a year later, it seems like the *STDIN* invocation can't and shouldn't work because it uses up *STDIN* twice.  Testing with large files (about 80 million lines) indicates it apparently works correctly.  Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Used idea of [hmontoliu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18717/17517) to implement simple command:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
delim="${1:-,}"
interm="${2:-\~}"
sed "s/$delim/$interm$delim/g" | column -t -s "$interm" | sed "s/  $delim/$delim/g"
```

Comment:

- `${1:-,}` - is a first argument with `,` as default
- the first `sed` inserts a intermediate symbol (`$interm` 2nd argument or `~` by default)
- then `column` replaces intermediate symbol with spaces that do alignment
- the second `sed` cleans up the redundant spaces after `column` command

Usage example:

```sh
$ echo "
a: bb: cccc
aaaa: b : cc
" | align :

a   : bb: cccc
aaaa: b : cc
```

It's also good in that it's idempotent: you can apply it several times and get the same result (for example when you edit in vim and realign).